# Using Google ReCaptcha on angular

Tags: angular, recaptcha

I am using [reCAPTCHA](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-recaptcha) on angular, and for a day or 2 it was working fine, but now I got a error which says

> We detected that your site is not verifying reCAPTCHA solutions. This is required for the proper use of reCAPTCHA on your site. Please see our developer site for more information.

I am using like it mention

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<re-captcha (resolved)="resolved($event)" siteKey="YOUR_SITE_KEY"></re-captcha>`,
}) export class MyApp {
    resolved(captchaResponse: string) {
        console.log(`Resolved captcha with response ${captchaResponse}:`);
    }
}
```

Am I missing something, do I manually need to do something with `${captchaResponse}` as I am using angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to post validate the response value, by calling this url from your backend

https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify

See here: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify

Comment: I thought, the response we get `    resolved(captchaResponse: string) {
        console.log(`Resolved captcha with response ${captchaResponse}:`);
    }` is a valid response?

Comment: No, you still need to validate that response. Otherwise, anybody could just add a response field to your form. From the link I provided: "After you get the response token, you need to verify it with reCAPTCHA using the following API to ensure the token is valid."

Comment: How Can I do make the call, I am fairly new to making JSON calls or angular HTTP calls.

Comment: It depends on what you use in your backed (java/php/nodejs...)

Comment: Java. But isn't this call goes from front end to google servers?

Comment: No, you need to verify it when you submit your form. So if you are using java, do a post to the provided URL in java.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163396/discussion-between-nofel-and-david).

Comment: Thanks @David ‍

Comment: Those links to the documentation are commonly available. Links to them does not have additional value.